# Asset/Inventory management system

Tags: inventory, digital-asset-management, asset-management

My company requires an asset/inventory management system that can manage predominantly IT infrastructure (i.e. switches, routers, IP phones etc...) for 50+ customers.

As such, we require that each item (identified through serial or MAC) can have a history of where it has moved from/to and where it currently is. It would also be good to have the ability to manage purchase orders (we are the only ones that use the purchase orders - the customers purchase is done through the quote).

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, thanks...